# Google Sheets: Displaying Data from one column into new column of MERGED cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using names listed in 1 column, I need to redisplay the same list of names in several sheets to filter info and add more info. It's a very complicated Google Sheet, otherwise I'd share it. I thought I'd make a model sheet, but the model sheet is doing exactly what I want:

*model works wonderfully*
[image]

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("---",FILTER(A2:A,ISTEXT(A2:A))),"-",TRUE,FALSE))`

Column C is the original problem, which seeks out the first, fourth, seventh etc. because the resulting fields are merged at those points.
Column D is the attempted solution, which takes all the fields, adds buffer punctuation between each ("-"), and then splits them transposed.

I tried the exact same equation in my convoluted sheet, but the original problem is still there:

*actual references other sheet data and does not work*
[image]

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("---",FILTER('REHEARSAL ATTENDANCE'!B4:B,ISTEXT('REHEARSAL ATTENDANCE'!B4:B))),"-",TRUE,FALSE))`

Is there a reason why it doesn't work?? I need them spaced out.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the "---" string to five dashes? "-----" Your sheet is spaced by 5 cells per entry instead of 3 on the model.

Comment: @CarlosM You could probably turn your comment to an answer. so as the OP can properly accept it. Not many read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Since your entries are spaced five cells apart instead of three in the model, you would need five dashes / repetitions as well.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("-----",FILTER('REHEARSAL ATTENDANCE'!B4:B,ISTEXT('REHEARSAL ATTENDANCE'!B4:B))),"-",TRUE,FALSE))
```

[image]